# What's wrong with this async/await method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm trying to set an image source property to a Uri that's returned in JSON from an API. The JSON object returned has two properties.

I've created the following helper class to query the API and extract the Uri property:

```
public class GetPicUri
{
    public GetPicUri()
    {
    }

    private string _uri;

    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://randompicture.api/random");
        HttpClient getResponse = new HttpClient();
        var json = await getResponse.GetStringAsync(uri);

        var picture = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Picture>(json);

        _uri = picture.Uri;
        return _uri;
    }
}
```

This is the model used for deserializing the JSON:

```
public class Picture
{
    public Picture()
    {
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I can't access the string property of the GetPicUri class:

```
var picUri = new GetPicUri();
string imageSource = picUri.Get();
```

When I try this I get an exception every time:

> cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'string'

I've tried slicing this a whole bunch of different ways, for example having the Uri as a static string, and having the Get method as `async Task` (or `void`) and have it just update the static string, and get called from the constructor. I've tried running it as the Get method for a property. But I can't get it to work.

So I guess I have two questions, the first being what am I doing wrong here specifically, and from a design perspective what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: `string imageSource = await picUri.Get();` and make the containing method `async` too.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you don't understand what a task is. A task of string is "I will give you a string in the future". So you cannot convert a task of string to a string; "I will give you a string in the future" and "I am a string" are two completely different things.

Comment: An await is an *asynchronous wait*. It means "if the future string is available now, get it; if it is not, find more work to do, do that work while we're waiting, and come back here when it is available". So to turn a task of string into a string, you await it.

Comment: ok, the problem then is that I have to make the method I'm calling it from async as well. Is there a correct approach for when I can't (or don't want to) do that? In this case the method I'm calling has to be async because the HttpClient requires it.

Comment: Support of asynchronous workflows is a property of programs, not methods. Make the whole call stack asynchronous, up to the event handler. Remember what I said: an await means *go find more work*. The whole program has to cooperate to determine what work can be done while you are asynchronously waiting.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert , that makes sense. I'll need to put some more thought into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice to add an `Aync` to the name of the method if it is in fact asynchronous - for example:

```
public async Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    var uri = new Uri("https://randompicture.api/random");
    HttpClient getResponse = new HttpClient();
    var json = await getResponse.GetStringAsync(uri);

    var picture = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Picture>(json);

    _uri = picture.Uri;
    return _uri;
}
```

call using:

```
await picUri.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

your get method is returning a Task (basically an object contains task info like status ,etc), any async method should return task (or void) , you need to asynchronously wait for this task to finish using the await key word

```
string imageSource = await picUri.Get();
```

using the above approach u will have to change the calling method also to async , and u will find the async keyword spreading into ur code

or force the method to behave synchronously by getting the Result property from the task object returned from get method (which is basically making it useless to declare the Get method as async )

```
string imageSource = picUri.Get().Result;
```

Comment: Note : there is rarely a good case for using `Result` or `Wait` on an `async` method.

Comment: Michael Randall's comment could be strengthened. **Do not synchronously wait on a task unless you know for certain that the task has completed**.  You will almost certainly produce a program that can deadlock if you do not follow this advice.